# Update featured row in table if other radio button choosen - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'am trying to make a featured photo for my product images. I have successfully made radio buttons with the product images id associated to them. When I click on a radio button and submit it, it sets a "featured" column in the product_images table to 1 ( or True). The problem I'm having is I only want 1 photo to be featured for each product. When I go choose and click a different image to be featured, it inserts it into the database with a 1 also.

How can  I make it so there is only 1 featured image per product. So if some other image is selected, make all other images default back to 0 (or False) with that product_id.

Here is my form:

```html
          <form method="post" action="/store/admin/products/add/featured/{{ $products->id }}">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                @foreach($products->photos as $set) 
                    <label>{{ $set->id }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="featured" value="{{ $set->id }}" {{ $set->featured === 1 ? "checked=checked" : "" }}>                       
                @endforeach


               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Feature Image</button>


            </form>
```

My function to insert featured image in DB:

```html
public function storeFeaturedPhoto($id, Request $request) {

        // Check if radio button is checked or not for featured image
        $featured = Input::has('featured') ? true : false;

        // Validate featured button
        $this->validate($request, [
            'featured' => 'required'
        ]);

        // Grab the ID of the Image being featured from radio button
        $featured2 = Input::get('featured');

        // Select All from product_images where the photo ID is the photo id being selected from radio button
        $image = ProductPhoto::where('id', '=', $featured2);


        // Select from product_images wherew featured = 1 and the product ID = to the product id in the URL, then count the results
        $count = ProductPhoto::where('featured', '=', 1)->where('product_id', '=', $id)->count();

        if ($count > 1) {
          // Do something here to deselect all other images with this product_id??????????
        }

        // update the product_photos table with the featured photo
        $image->update([
            'featured' => $featured,
        ]);

        // Return redirect back
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

My product_images table:
[image: My Product Images Table]

And my form:
[image: Upload form with select featured image form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, justy add some lines in ProductPhoto Model.

```
class ProductPhoto extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['featured'];

    //other things...
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function storeFeaturedPhoto($id, Request $request) {
        // Validate featured button
        $this->validate($request, [
            'featured' => 'required|exists:product_images,id'
        ]);

        // Grab the ID of the Image being featured from radio button
        $featured = Input::get('featured');

        // Some mass updates
        ProductPhoto::where('product_id', '=', $id)->update(['featured' => 0]);
        ProductPhoto::findOrFail($featured)->update(['featured' => 1]);


        // Return redirect back
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form method="post" action="/store/admin/products/add/featured/{{ $products->id }}">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                @foreach($products->photos as $set) 
                    <label>{{ $set->id }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="featured" value="{{ $set->id }}">                       
                @endforeach


               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Feature Image</button>


            </form>
```

controller

```
    public function storeFeaturedPhoto($id, Request $request) {

            // Check if radio button is checked or not for featured image
            // Grab the ID of the Image being featured from radio button

            $featured = $request->input('featured');


            // Validate featured button
            $this->validate($request, [
                'featured' => 'required'
            ]);



            // Select All from product_images where the photo ID is the photo id being selected from radio button
            $image = ProductPhoto::findOrfail($featured);
 //radio buttom! u lust have only one selected  thats how it works  i think (in groups) use check box and exlain this part more


            // Select from product_images wherew featured = 1 and the product ID = to the product id in the URL, then count the results

            $count = ProductPhoto::where('featured', '=', 1)->where('product_id', '=', $id)->get();

            if ($count > 1) {
              foreach ($count as $prod)
     {
      $prod->featured = 0;
      $prod->save();
      }
            }

            // update the product_photos table with the featured photo
            $image->update([
                'featured' => $featured,
            ]);

            // Return redirect back
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function storeFeaturedPhoto($id, Request $request) {
   $this->validate($request, [
     'featured' => 'required|exists:product_images,id'
   ]);

   $featured = Input::get('featured');
   if($featured==1){
      ProductPhoto::where(['featured'=>1])->update(['featured' => 0]);
   }
   ProductPhoto::where('product_id', '=', $id)->update(['featured' => 1]);
   // Return redirect back
   return redirect()->back();
}
```